# Closed form expression for $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{k4^k}{n+k}{n+k\choose n-k}{n\choose k}{2n\choose 2k}^{-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, closed-form

I'm trying to find a closed form expression (that doesn't involve an indefinite summation) for the following combinatorial sum :
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\left[\frac{k4^k}{n+k}{n+k\choose n-k}\frac{\displaystyle{n\choose k}}{\displaystyle{2n\choose 2k}}\right]$$
I don't know wether or not there is one in the first place.
The context in which this sum arised isn't relevant and won't provide any help.

I don't have any idea as of where to even start. Any suggestion ?

Comment: I'd start by computing the first few values, maybe up to $n=10$ or so, and see if any pattern emerges. If say, the numerators were not smooth (having large prime divisors) I'd be pessimistic about there being a closed formula.

Comment: Perhaps try the first few values on OEIS?

Comment: The first few values are $0, 2, \frac{28}{3}, \frac{198}{5}, \frac{1144}{7}, \frac{41990}{63}, \frac{29716}{11}$. Except for the fact that this sequence is unsurprisingly increasing, I don't see any recognisable pattern...

Since this is not a sequence of integers, I unfortunately can't try them on OEIS.

Comment: Maybe it helps to see that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{k4^k}{n+k}\frac{\binom{n+k}{n-k}\binom{n}{k}}{\binom{2n}{2k}}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}4^{n-k}\frac{\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n-k-1}{n}}{\binom{2n}{n}}
$$
and concentrate on the numerator which is an integer.

Comment: Stars and bars and $$\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{x^k}{4^k}\binom{2k}{k}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}$$ are enough to deduce that the sum equals $$\frac{2n}{2n+1}\binom{4n}{2n}\binom{2n}{n}^{-1},$$ see my solution below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Wolfgang Kais' rearrangement,

$$ \frac{4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{4^k}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{n+(n-1-k)}{n} $$
is a convolution which equals
$$ \frac{4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}[x^{n-1}]\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{1}{4^m}\binom{2m}{m}x^m \sum_{m\geq 0}\binom{n+m}{n}x^m $$
or
$$ \frac{4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}} [x^{n-1}]\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}\cdot\frac{1}{(1-x)^{n+1}}=\frac{4^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}[x^{n-1}](1-x)^{-(n+3/2)}=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}4^n\binom{-n-3/2}{n-1}}{\binom{2n}{n}} $$
which simplifies into
$$\frac{2 \sqrt{\pi } n \,\Gamma \left(2 n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{(2 n+1)\, \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}=\color{red}{\frac{2n}{2n+1}\cdot\frac{\binom{4n}{2n}}{\binom{2n}{n}}}.$$

Comment: Why the downvote? This provides a closed formula with a rather simple technique.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks !

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio - most of these downvoters of good solutions  are just jealous. I dont see other reasons.

Comment: @AliShather I agree with you too.

Answer (score 1):

You can always look for an expression in terms of the hypergeometric function, which has a lot of nice properties.

Indeed, Wolframalpha says your sum can be written like this:
$$\frac{2n}{2n-1}\ _2F_1(1-n,n+1;3/2-n;1)$$
The website also offers a small list of values for different $n$. This list indicates divergence of the sum.

But I don't see how this will be helpful, unless there is more information about what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

$$S_n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\left[\frac{k4^k}{n+k}{n+k\choose n-k}\frac{\displaystyle{n\choose k}}{\displaystyle{2n\choose 2k}}\right]=-\frac{n}{\sqrt \pi}\frac{ \Gamma \left(-n-\frac{1}{2} \right) \Gamma \left(-n+\frac{1}{2} 
   \right)}{  \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}-2n\right)}$$

For large values of $n$, using Stirling-like approximations,
$$\log(S_n)=2 n \log (2)-\frac{\log (2)}{2}-\frac{7}{16 n}+\frac{1}{8 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$S_n \sim 2^{2 n-\frac{1}{2}}\exp\left(-\frac{7}{16 n}+\frac{1}{8 n^2} \right)$$ which seems to be quite good even for small $n$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{aproximation} & \text{exact} \\
 1 & 2.06932 & 2.00000 \\
 2 & 9.37939 & 9.33333 \\
 3 & 39.6609 & 39.6000 \\
 4 & 163.537 & 163.429 \\
 5 & 666.739 & 666.508 \\
 6 & 2702.00 & 2701.45 \\
 7 & 10911.1 & 10909.7 \\
 8 & 43960.5 & 43956.7 \\
 9 & 176841. & 176830. \\
 10 & 710604. & 710572.
\end{array}
\right)$$